# Is it possible to edit a moderator attention flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged a question, intending to suggest it be moved to the language learners site but realized after I submitted it that I had typed "ELU" instead. I did not see anywhere I could edit my flag reason and clicking the flag button again told me I could not re-flag the same question. As I expected, when the moderator saw my flag they declined it and said "This *is* ELU..."

Is there a way I could have corrected that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can fix your mistake by retracting the flag, then reflagging with the fixed message.

> [image: this is the flag you currently have raised, retract flag button]

If you don't remember what you wrote, you can check your flag history. Retracted flags are shown as "self-removed", but you can still see what you said:

> [image: under the post name is the flag text, your name, and a timestamp]

Note that retracted flags still count against your daily flag count — they're not free. Fortunately, most people have more than enough flags each day.

This feature was added in [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/323179).

Answer (score -3):

No. You can always reflag a question if it wasn't obvious what you meant and the flag was declined.

That said, in this case, the moderator also included additional information in the decline reason as to why a migration to ELL did not take place (yes, we know you meant ELL; we just don't want you to get into the habit of mixing up the sites and confusing everyone).

Comment: So, I would just wait for the decline (or approval)?

Comment: Can one reflag? I'm not sure that once you've flagged a q/a and it's been declined that you still can flag.